# Windows 7 hangs at grub's purple screen when dual booting

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I have installed a new laptop (Lenovo Z510) for dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 64 bit. After several trials it now works, but I have a strange effect.

I always enter the Grub purple screen fine. Ubuntu always works. When I want to boot Windows however windows boots fine (I hear the Windows start sound) but I only see a blank, purple Grub like screen. I can operate Windows though, pressing three times the tab key and then enter shuts the PC down successfully.

Sometime a trick works like that: I press just the power key and the PC hibernates. When I switch on the PC afterward and choose Win7 in Grub again everything is working fine, this time with working screen. However I had to find the trick does not always work - maybe whether it works or not is just random :-(

The workaround is quite dirty, what can I do to get rid of it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have same problem with 13.10, hope we'll find a solution

Comment: The problem is still there. I have not found a solution yet. Whenever the problem shows up I just reboot and try again...

Comment: Did you try [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) ?

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem (I was able to listen to the windows login sound even when the only think I saw was the grub purple screen).

Luckily I found a workaround:

- move the file `30_os-prober` to `06_os-prober` (because I wanted the windows entries to be listed first)
- run `sudo upgrade-grub`

And now it works fine every time... I do not not understand why and I have not tried to isolate if `update-grub` is enough or not.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me! The issue occurred after windows tried to update itself and then got stuck on a purple screen after the grub boot options.

Answer (score 1):

So this sort of worked for me. I moved the `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` file to `/etc/grub.d/06_os-prober`, then ran `update-grub`.

This puts windows on the top of the grub boot screen. Then I tried many different options to start, restart from windows and ubuntu and what I have noticed so far is if I let the boot via grub,  proceed by it self with no manual intervention and let the default 10s pass, it will boot into windows with no issues.

However if I manually select the "Windows 7" option in the grub boot screen using my cursor and then hit enter, I get the dreaded purple screen in windows.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience,  this issue can appears if Video card drivers were not installed into the Windows system properly  (Win 7 in my case).

The steps which helped me :

1. Boot into Ubuntu
2. Edit `/etc/default/grub` and uncomment the line `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`, then execute `sudo update-grub`
3. Restart and boot into Windows
4. Install / Reinstall Video card drivers (Intel HD + nVidia in my case)
5. Restart and boot into Ubuntu again
6. Restore `/etc/default/grub` to the previous state (comment `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`), execute `sudo update-grub` again.

Done.

*Tested on:*
*Dell Inspiron 15 3000 Series, Os: Windows 7 x64, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64*

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr9zS.jpg) is the purple screen I was seeing and this answer was the solution for my case. Moving the grub entry as suggested in other answers had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
I noticed I was booting to the 1st partition, the windows boot partition ~200mb
When I instead selected the partition with Windows system installed on it, the boot proceeded normally

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when upgrading my dual boot Lenovo T440s from Windows 7 to Windows 10. It always worked fine with Win7 until the upgrade rebooted to start Win10. I then only saw the purple screen.

I booted into Ubuntu 14.04 and modified `/etc/default/grub` to uncomment `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` to disable graphical mode and changed `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to `3`. After I ran `sudo update-grub` and rebooting, Win10 booted just fine. However, I then re-enabled graphical mode, changed default back to `0`, ran `sudo update-grub`, and Win10 still booted fine.

So I think just running `sudo update-grub` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. It's more to do with Legacy v/s UEFI Boot mode.
 Win 7 is installed in Legacy mode while it's other way round for win 8.1 and above. If both win 10 and Ubuntu are installed in Legacy mode (for eg. if win 7 upgraded to 10). This issue may come.
For me just disabling legacy mode from BIOS and enabling it again worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have found a temporary solution to the problem... just go into your BIOS settings and set Windows bootloader to boot first (before Ubuntu)...