# After dual booting, windows 7 blank

Tags: grub2, windows-7

i am new to ubuntu
i just installed ubuntu 14 on my windows 7. The ubuntu works well. But when i want to enter windows 7, the screen went purple. I can still hear the sound of the windows. so graphic is the problem.

there might already be a solution, but i do not know how to do this part "move the file 30_os-prober to 06_os-prober" in [Windows 7 hangs at grub's purple screen when dual booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433388/windows-7-hangs-at-grubs-purple-screen-when-dual-booting).

I found the etc folder already including 30 and 06 os prober, but what does "move" mean and how to "move" it. do i have to do it from terminal?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Have you tried this way**

open terminal and type this :

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

search for `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`
and replace it with `#GRUB_TERMINAL=console`
then save the file and boot to your windows if not works then tell please